# How to get parameterized query with iBatis-Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, ibatis

I'm working on an application with spring-ibatis integration in which I have to log some of the query performed. So what I'd like to do, is basically getting the SQL from the ibatis mapped statements in the XML config file and then add somehow the parameters. I've been able to get the query with this lines of code:

```
MappedStatement ms = (MappedStatement) ((SqlMapClientImpl) sqlMapClient)
    .getDelegate().getMappedStatement(queryId);

ms.setParameterClass(HashMap.class);
RequestScope scope = new RequestScope();
scope.setStatement(ms);

String sql = ((DynamicSql) ms.getSql()).getSql(scope, params);
```

So with the first row I get the MappedStatement and with the last one I get the raw query. The problem is that even if I'm passing to it the object with the query parameters, the SQL still has the parameters placeholders '?' (in the XML query they are named parameters, not positionals).

I have tried to set the `parameterClass` field instead of the `parameterMap` as suggested [here](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s04.html) but with no success. I'm not sure on how to work with the inline parameters.

I'm using `ibatis-sqlmap 2.3.0` and `spring-ibatis 2.0.8`.

As you have probably noticed I have little to no knowledge of iBatis. Also, please I know that this is dirty and that I'm using classes that I'm not supposed to, no need to point that out.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The SQL correctly has `?` placeholder because internally parametrized query is executed. The SQL is not updated with parameters values to have just one string but instead a string with ? is send and parameter value is sent to let DB use the parameters. Try to find a list of parameters and use them replacing ? marks with values. BTW which problem you are trying to resolve? Why do you need the SQL string at all?

Comment: I need to query to log it in a DB. I already saw that iBatis let's you configure the logging but the project I'm working on implemented a custom logger to solve this problem. I've already solved this problem with iBatis static query since as you said I just replace the ? with my parameters. The problem is that those I'm working on are dynamic queries and thus the number and position of parameters are variables.

Comment: I am afraid it's not so simple in common case. Imagine your are inserting a blob to DB. How to print it in the log? I would log SQL and all the parameters (by toString() calls) separately. so I would suggest 2 log lines to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem and I want to share the solution for future readers that may have the same issue. Before doing that, keep in mind that this is NOT the way you should work with iBatis but only a dirty workaround to get the underlying SQL.

First of all, we need to group iBatis queries in at least 2 groups:

1. *[Static queries](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s03.html)*, they are simple mapped statements without any conditional elements.
2. *[Dynamic queries](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html)*, they are mapped statements with conditional elements (e.g. `isEqual`, `isGreaterThan`, `isNull`...).

Once you have done this difference, here's the code to get the SQL:

```
public static String getSQLFromDynamicQuery(SqlMapClient sqlMapClient,
        String queryId, Object paramObject) {

    // Gets the SQL and parameters.
    MappedStatement ms = ((SqlMapClientImpl) sqlMapClient).getDelegate()
            .getMappedStatement(queryId);
    RequestScope scope = new RequestScope();
    scope.setStatement(ms);
    String sql = ((DynamicSql) ms.getSql()).getSql(scope, paramObject);
    Object[] params = ms.getSql().getParameterMap(scope, paramObject)
            .getParameterObjectValues(scope, paramObject);

    // Adds params to the query.
    return bindQueryParam(sql, params);
}

public String getSQLFromStaticQuery(SqlMapClient sqlMapClient,
        String queryId, Object... params) {

    // Gets the SQL.
    String sql = ((StaticSql) ((SqlMapClientImpl) sqlMapClient)
            .getDelegate().getMappedStatement(queryId).getSql()).getSql(
            null, null);

    // Adds params to the query.
    if (params != null) {
        sql = bindQueryParam(sql, params);
    }

    return sql;
}

public static String bindQueryParam(String sql, Object... params) {
    String result = sql;
    for (Object param : params) {
        result = result.replaceFirst("\\?",
                param == null ? "null" : param.toString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

The `bindQueryParam` method replaces the question marks in the query with an array of object. For a static query, you will have to pass that array meanwhile for the dynamic one you can pass an `Object` or a `java.util.Map`, according to what is your `parameterClass` of the Mapped Statement.

Both methods use explicit subcasting (I've spent a lot of time looking at the source code to figure out how to make this work as you can imagine), so you may want to pay attention to call the right method according to the Mapped Statement you are processing or you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Again, this is not the recommended way but it works if you need it.